# Show views active filter values as pills without using Facets

Tags: 7, views

I have this requirement where selected filter values need to appear as "pills" on the page with an "x" which, when clicked, would unset the filter and reload the search without that value. I've used [Active Facet Pills](https://www.drupal.org/project/active_facet_pills) once before to achieve this. However, the view I'm working with is just a plain vanilla view (no facets). I've done a lot of searching, but nothing seems to come up on how to implement this.

How does one achieve this in D7 views?

Answer (score 0):

[Facet API](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi) seems to be the common module for Facets in D7.

It seems there is the "Summary" option that is the "pills" feature you're looking for.